Long boot time ~3min staring at black screen with only steady cursor bar before disk encryption password prompt. Macbook Pro 7,1 (mid 2010)
I'm a casual Linux user who can usually Google my way through problems, but I'm hitting a brick wall here.
Since installing Ubuntu some of my boot times have been very acceptable. I am seeing a lot related to snaps. Could that be the reason? Also I have not managed to be able to see the grub screen. I have tried editing the grub file. Honestly I'm at a bit of a loss there. Most other laptops I installed Ubuntu on were fine in this regard, but this is my first old Apple so after the chimes and the gray screen it just hangs on a black screen. It's like the graphical mode is not correct. The steady white cursor is upper mid left like if an 800x600 pixel image was displaying on a higher resolution screen like 1280x800.
Results of systemd-analyze blame :
    35.445s snap.docker.nvidia-container-toolkit.service
12.416s gpu-manager.service
 6.968s snapd.seeded.service
 6.567s NetworkManager.service
 6.355s vboxdrv.service
 5.686s snapd.service
 5.292s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 3.087s apport.service
 2.886s dev-loop35.device
 2.882s dev-loop27.device
 2.829s dev-loop26.device
 2.784s dev-loop33.device
 2.771s dev-loop24.device
 2.768s dev-loop28.device
 2.764s dev-loop21.device
 2.759s dev-loop31.device
 2.758s dev-loop25.device
 2.753s dev-loop29.device
 2.749s dev-loop32.device
 2.744s udisks2.service
 2.739s dev-loop16.device
 2.725s dev-loop19.device
 2.720s dev-loop30.device
 2.714s dev-loop23.device
 2.668s dev-loop20.device
 2.653s dev-loop34.device
 2.643s dev-loop17.device
 2.627s dev-loop22.device
 2.626s dev-loop18.device
 2.624s dev-loop14.device
 2.615s dev-loop15.device
 2.450s dev-loop13.device
 2.381s dev-loop12.device
 2.376s dev-loop11.device
 2.313s dev-loop10.device
 2.089s dev-loop9.device
 2.088s dev-loop8.device
 2.040s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dubuntu\x2d\x2dlv.device
 1.935s rsyslog.service
 1.848s accounts-daemon.service
 1.846s iio-sensor-proxy.service
 1.769s polkit.service
 1.729s snapd.apparmor.service
 1.543s apparmor.service
 1.434s systemd-logind.service
 1.132s switcheroo-control.service
 1.088s cups.service
  909ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  903ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  901ms systemd-hostnamed.service
  824ms ModemManager.service
  801ms e2scrub_reap.service
  794ms systemd-journald.service
  772ms keyboard-setup.service
  673ms avahi-daemon.service
  673ms plymouth-start.service
  662ms grub-common.service
  619ms systemd-modules-load.service
  608ms snap-bare-5.mount
  603ms user@1000.service
  590ms zramswap.service
  589ms systemd-udevd.service
  572ms snap-chromium\x2dffmpeg-65.mount
  567ms tlp.service
  565ms lm-sensors.service
  563ms snap-chromium\x2dffmpeg-69.mount
  556ms snap-core18-2846.mount
  543ms snap-core20-2434.mount
  537ms snap-core22-1663.mount
  534ms systemd-resolved.service
  529ms snap-core22-1722.mount
  522ms snap-docker-2932.mount
  519ms dbus.service
  519ms snap-docker-2963.mount
  489ms snap-firefox-5361.mount
  484ms snap-firefox-5437.mount
  460ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-198.mount
  445ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-176.mount
  444ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  442ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  435ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1536.mount
  427ms snap-kf5\x2d5\x2d113\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2d11\x2dcore22-1.mount
  418ms snap-libinput-69.mount
  411ms bluetooth.service
  406ms sysstat.service
  403ms snap-mesa\x2dcore22-311.mount
  395ms snap-obsidian-40.mount
  383ms snap-opera-350.mount
  376ms lvm2-monitor.service
  372ms snap-opera-351.mount
  357ms snap-pygpt-336.mount
  352ms snap-pygpt-338.mount
  348ms snap-skype-378.mount
  341ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1244.mount
  329ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1248.mount
  323ms snap-snapd-21759.mount
  322ms wpa_supplicant.service
  313ms thermald.service
  310ms snap-snapd-23258.mount
  302ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-247.mount
  301ms dev-loop3.device
  300ms dev-loop0.device
  298ms colord.service
  296ms dev-loop5.device
  283ms dev-loop2.device
  283ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-253.mount
  278ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  272ms dev-loop4.device
  269ms dev-loop1.device
  268ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-187.mount
  263ms snap-ubuntu\x2dbudgie\x2dwelcome-536.mount
  262ms dev-loop7.device
  261ms dev-loop6.device
  260ms update-notifier-download.service
  249ms snap-thunderbird-593.mount
  240ms snap-thunderbird-609.mount
  219ms upower.service
  218ms snap-ubuntu\x2dbudgie\x2dwelcome-530.mount
  217ms alsa-restore.service
  212ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
  210ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:0a.0\x2data\x2d1.0\x2dp>
  205ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  190ms systemd-binfmt.service
  169ms systemd-sysctl.service
  166ms snap-vlc-3777.mount
  161ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-375d52b1\x2de4c4\x2d4607\x2d9af7\x2d91>
  158ms tmp.mount
  155ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  151ms modprobe@drm.service
  150ms console-setup.service
  148ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  145ms systemd-udev-load-credentials.service
  144ms vboxautostart-service.service
  137ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
  133ms dev-hugepages.mount
  131ms plymouth-read-write.service
  130ms dev-mqueue.mount
  127ms run-lock.mount
  117ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  113ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  112ms modprobe@fuse.service
  110ms lightdm.service
  105ms systemd-user-sessions.service
  102ms swap.img.swap
  101ms ufw.service
   99ms systemd-random-seed.service
   97ms blk-availability.service
   89ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   86ms systemd-backlight@leds:smc::kbd_backlight.service
   83ms modprobe@configfs.service
   81ms systemd-backlight@backlight:nv_backlight.service
   80ms boot-efi.mount
   74ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   64ms dev-zram0.device
   61ms systemd-cryptsetup@dm_crypt\x2d0.service
   57ms vboxweb-service.service
   55ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   54ms boot.mount
   52ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   51ms rtkit-daemon.service
   48ms openvpn.service
   48ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   40ms sysstat-collect.service
   34ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   32ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   19ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   17ms setvtrgb.service
    5ms snapd.socket
lines 146-168/168 (END)

systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @51.668s
└─multi-user.target @51.668s
  └─snap.docker.dockerd.service @51.667s
    └─network.target @16.188s
      └─NetworkManager.service @9.619s +6.567s
        └─dbus.service @9.079s +519ms
          └─basic.target @8.954s
            └─sockets.target @8.952s
              └─snapd.socket @8.945s +5ms
                └─sysinit.target @8.921s
                  └─systemd-backlight@backlight:nv_backlight.service @14.809s +81ms
                    └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @7.507s
                      └─system.slice @2.078s
                        └─-.slice @2.078s

